# Pod Install on M1 Error AFTER sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi & Ruby Update

Tags: terminal, rubygems, cocoapods, pod-install

I have been researching how to get `pod install` to work on my M1 but I am still stuck. This issue has come up before and I've tried the following:

1. Running `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
2. Updated ruby and setting it to override the path (my ruby version is 3.1)
3. Running both `arch -x86_64 pod install` and `pod install`

Updating Ruby fixed a portion of the errors, but I am still left with this error set when I run `pod install`

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:228:in `initialize_from_file': [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version (56). (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:113:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1190:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1189:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1189:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1184:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:106:in `analyze'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Do you have any other suggestions to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur because Ruby has not fully compatible with the latest version of Xcode. In order to fix it you need to set the `Project Format` to an earlier version (try choosing `Xcode 13.0`) and then run `pod install --verbose`. Good luck!

[image: project format]