# Cocoapods Error in Flutter Project in M1 Mac

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, cocoapods

Recently I have been building a Flutter Project. After I added cloud Firestore to my project, I couldn't run my app. I have already tried the solutions that are provided on the internet but still can not run them.

What I have tried before:

```
flutter clean & flutter run
```

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
sudo gem install ffi
```

delete the podfile.lock in ios

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Here is the error message:

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing
    Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.1.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.1.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.1.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `jitsi_meet` from `.symlinks/plugins/jitsi_meet/ios`
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL, retries: 4
      CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL, retries: 3
      CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL, retries: 2
      CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL, retries: 1
    [!] CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:407:in `block in download_and_save_with_retries_async'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:406:in `apply'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1205:in `apply'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1729:in `block (2 levels) in on_resolvable'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1582:in `evaluate_to'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1729:in `block in on_resolvable'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:353:in `run_task'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:342:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:325:in `loop'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:325:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:324:in `catch'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:324:in `block in create_worker'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1257:in `raise'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1257:in `wait_until_resolved!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:977:in `wait!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
Exited
```

Anyone can help??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error reported when using Pod to access CallKits SDK of ZEGOCLOUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74216388/error-reported-when-using-pod-to-access-callkits-sdk-of-zegocloud)

Answer (score 1):

On Apple Mac with M1 you can run these commands:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
arch -arm64 brew install cocoapods
arch -arm64 brew reinstall cocoapods
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Comment: The whole solution worked for me while I was struggling to install cocoapods.
But, for mac m1 you need to: arch -arm64 brew install cocoapods.
Anyway, you solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run this from the command:

```
sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
```

Comment: Still not work. FYI, when I sudo arch -x86_64 pod install --allow-root, the terminal shows No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Comment: try running this from ios folder. type cd ios, then run the above

Comment: I tried it. It shows cd: no such file or directory: ios

Comment: are you running terminal from android studio?

Comment: no, running from VS code.

Comment: Try read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74528991/1138498 it may be the solution for you.